# Football Training

Tags: workout

I just turned 15 yesterday and I seem to be in a pickle. I weigh currently 178 and I am 5 '10'. I am currently going to try and play outside linebacker or even a Defensive End. I have been taking C4 cellucore Pre-Workout, with Amino Energy mid workout, followed by Gold Standard Whey protein. I am looking for someone to recommend a plan of what I should do concerning workouts and or what other supplements I should take instead. I am a Freshman who next year will be a sophmore who is looking to start JV. Thanks!

Comment: This seems like a question more appropriate for your coaches. Especially since we don't know you and your coaches will know what you should work on.

Comment: Have a look at the work of Joe Defranco (https://www.defrancostraining.com/) he was at one time (and possibly still is, I haven't kept up of late) the go-to guy for getting people through the NFL combine.
Most importantly though, get on a decent training program, eat a good, healthy diet THEN, once those two things are in place, THEN look at what supplements could help. Supplement's won't magically make you superman, they're supposed to supplement hard work and a healthy diet, hence the name.

Answer (score 1):

Keep it simple. Do GOMAD (drink a gallon of whole milk a day) and run Starting Strength. You will get really strong and will pack on weight to properly handle defensive end. Once or twice a week, add in 20 hill sprints or Prowler pushes for anaerobic capacity.

Comment: And, your answer is based on....?

Comment: He wants to grow and get stronger. He doesn't need fancy stuff. The best way to do that via a big calorie surplus and consistent strength gains.

Comment: This would be the perfect program for what you're doing.  The only thing you would change if you couldn't do cleans, is swap it for the bent-over row.

Answer (score 0):

First, you do not need all of those supplements. A sound diet(ie. getting your vitamins,minerals,and veggies) and a protein shake here or there(I recommend the EAS Complete) will be enough to see strength gains.

If you are not strength training I suggest you start. 2 to 3 days a week. There are a ton of different programs out there, just find one and do it. Also be sure to do endurance cardio as well as power cardio(sprints). Cardio will help you maintain a high level of exertion for longer period of time

Finally, position drills and skills training are super valuable in football.
Footwork drills like this(https://youtu.be/6SiDrfWbMIo) you can do on your own and will help with agility. Yes these are DB drills but quick feet and acceleration help all positions. For OLB the "W" style drills are perfect.